# laravel blade template - how to remove a part from extended page

Tags: laravel, extend, laravel-blade

*Note: Like i said in the comment, i am working relatively large project. I can't change existing codes. Just try to add some code blocks for one page.*

I have a template blade. It has meta yield. But also included one meta.blade.php, that contains all meta tags. But i don't want to include metapage for some of my pages. There is the template for visualization:

**my_template**

```
<header>
    @yield('meta')
    @include('metapage')

    @yield('style')
    @yield('js')
</header>
```

**my view.blade.php**

```
@extends('my_template')

@section('meta')
    <meta description...>
@endsection

@section('style')
    //content
@endsection

@section('js')
    //content
@endsection
```

My question is: Is there a way to make something like this:

```
@extends('my_template')->except('metapage')
```

I know there isn't exist something like that. But i need that. I hope somebody can give me a solution.

Comment: I can't. Because there are so many pages. I am working on existing project. I just need to ignore included meta.blade for just one page.

Comment: Nice question Laravel should work on it. Laravel only provide a solution which is removing of subparts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain solution which I do:

- First one is to create multiple template and extend them as your requirements.
- Second one is to disable sub parts.
- Third one to create parent template having little things, then create child template which is extending parent and do extra things here. use it as your need.

If You are working on existing project and you have a lot of pages then First & third one is a better solution for it because you could make changes only in front end without affecting class code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the meta a component rather than an include, then your template would look the same and your view would be e.g.

```
@extends('my_template')

@section('meta')
    @component('meta')
        @slot('description', 'my amazing description')
    @endcomponent
@endsection

// other code here as usual
```

Your component is then responsible for checking what exists and what doesn't, e.g. like this:

```
@isset($description)
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $description }}">
@endisset

@isset($title)
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
@endisset

// etc, the title is just an example
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: Zoe, thanks for wanting to improve the post, but please do not make editations that do not improve it. Some people, like me, prefer to see the link in plain text, and it's still clickable so there's no loss of function. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the Tag Name Which You Want To ignore And Apply the CSS
ex: If I need to Remove the Footer From the Extended Page  make

```
footer {
    display: none;
}
```